# Are concave functions always smaller or equal to their linear extrapolations?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm actually trying to show that a function is non-decreasing, so a more complete statement of the problem would be:

Let $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a strictly positive concave function, with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0, \forall x \in (0,\infty)$. Show that $f(x)$ is non-decreasing.

I have been able to prove this based on the assumption that $f$ is smaller than its linear extrapolation $p(x)$ (due to it being concave), and a decreasing $f$ would imply a $p(x)$ tending to $-\infty$ on its limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$. But can't prove the assumption. Can I get any help?

Comment: how are you defining linear extrapolation?

Comment: assume an interval $[a,b] \subset [0,\infty)$, for any $x > b$, I'm defining the extrapolation:

$$
p(x) = f(a)+ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} (x-a)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is concave, we have   $f(x+t(y-x)) \le f(x)+t(f(y)-f(x))$ for $t >1$.

In particular, if $x<y$ we must have $f(x) \le f(y)$, otherwise we would have $f(z) <0$ for some $z$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm the only one who can't see it... but how do I prove that
$$
f(x+t(y-x)) \le f(x)+t(f(y)-f(x)) \qquad for \qquad t >1
$$

Comment: Suppose it is false for some $t>1$, let $z$ be the point corresponding to $t$. Then $y $ is a convex combination of $x,z$ but the value at $y$ lies above the line through the graph of $f$ at $x,z$.

Comment: @copper.hat Should the inequality be reversed?

Comment: @angryavian: No. Draw a concave function. Draw a secant. The points 'inside' must lie above and the points 'outside' must lie below.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the clarification, I overlooked the "$t>1$"

Comment: @copper.hat I'm sorry man... this is still not clear for me. Maybe I should've added an ELI5 tag. I'll keep trying to work it out with the hints you gave me. Thanks.

Comment: @PedroLima: First get the intuition. Draw a typical concave function and draw a line that cuts the graph at two points. Then the points in between are above the line and the other points are below. Now translate that into symbols.